# how to implement user identity within program with orbitb-db? ownership and granting/revoking writes? decentralized, no 3d-party services and no ipns?

Tags: identity, ipfs, orbitdb

- orbitdb says it cant do it https://github.com/orbitdb/field-manual/blob/684c7a1aa427c9acfe4d73cd28d64880e072b086/01_Tutorial/06_Identity_Permission.md#on-security
- but users want to give/take writing permissions to dbs

how to implement user model without 3d-party services or ipns?

Answer (score 0):

what to use for user identity?

- peer-id and private-key
- specifically - of ipfs node -  a config json file that node generates
- running ipfs init /path/to/config allows to create same node with identity
- it is simple - no need for DIDs - it works as SSH keys

ownership

- program starts with discovery - users need to be able to discover dbs, like we can discover repos on github
- program creates a public orbitdb database anyone can write to
- users publish the dbs they want others to see to that list
- and - when the write they also write name of db
- if same name - how do we now that this db is actually from owner we expect? by peer-id
- every message on pubsub - and also orbidb write entries - have peer-id of who posted them
- so program shows name of db and peer-id of author - this way we know that that record in discovery db is exactly from that peer
- and - as long as config file with peer-id and private-key is not lost - that person owns that identity

how to add/revoke writes in orbitdb without re-creating new db with new id? without 3d party services or ipns?

- this is brilliant
- an owner - always an owner - wants to give/take permissions
- once owner creates db, program also creates a access-cotrol database - a list simply - with write permissions only to owner
- other peers clone owner's db - and program also clones access-control db
- program implements custom access-controller that reads from access-controller db and checks - is peer listed there? then they can write
- no third party anything needed - all is already done within orbitdb
- and that access controller list already decentralized and persistent and replicatable

is orbitdb id needed? is orbitb/keystore needed?

- no
- if program were to use ObritDBAccessController - where permissions are give by orbitdb id - then yes
- but it is useless - we can add or revoke
- and  - as said above - the better solution is access-controll-peer-id-list-db that comes with each database
- and for that - custom access-controller is needed
- and since we have that - why would we make it use orbitdb identity when peer-id is much better - it is the identity of user, that they can persist and backup and they init ipfs from again
- one identity -  ipfs node config json file with peer-id and private-key

Comment: and - the access-controller-db's id can be written as the first record into the actual db it belongs to - this way that id it always readable from database itself

Comment: and - since orbitdb has key-value store - we can use that with Arthur-Dent - who is datahike on nodejs - to actually read and write to datalog db and have that be replicated - no need for two in parallel - orbitdb as decentralized key-value store, Arthur-Dent as the sane db

Comment: Arthur-Dent - datahike on nodejs - now has orbitdb backend as alternative to indexeddb
- https://github.com/move-me-to-ipfs-shipyard/Fennec/blob/ae7eb4ffcaed2ab93648d34a5e1a0a27f6484e40/src/Fennec/beans.cljs#L49
- https://github.com/move-me-to-ipfs-shipyard/Arthur-Dent/blob/8e6087a58895c23424e89da46a7a8e61c1318dc3/konserve/src/konserve/orbitdb.cljs